# Shapefile zooming to plot with geopandas

Tags: pandas, plot, shapefile, geopandas

I have a shapefile of Italy and I'm plotting the GIS Data on it. Thing is I've got a small trajectory of a bus going within a city(Rome) and when i`m plotting, it appears like 1 dot. I guess because of my map.

How to zoom the map (.shp) ?

```
street_map = gpd.read_file("roads.shp")
...
...
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,15))
street_map.plot(ax = ax, alpha = 0.4, color = "grey")
geo_df[geo_df['Perc_'] > 25].plot(ax = ax, markersize = 20, color = "blue", 
marker = "o", label = "Neg")
geo_df[geo_df['Perc_'] < 25].plot(ax = ax, markersize = 20, color = "red", 
marker = "^", label = "Pos")
plt.legend(prop={'size':15})
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Based on your 1st image, it is possible to get the zoom-in plot by specifying proper x and y limits.

```
...
ax.set_ylim([40.4, 47.2])
ax.set_xlim([7.0, 14.4])
```

(Place this code before `plt.legend()`.

Hope this is useful.